# How to copy keyframes from one action to other

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

I would like to know how to copy keyframes from one armature to another. The thing is, I have the same object, the same armature - the same everything - but in diferent blend files. I want to have all the animation in a single blend file. Can any one explain how to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this script will copy the animation data from the **active** Object **to** the **selected** object:

```
import bpy

active_obj = bpy.context.object
ad = bpy.context.object.animation_data

properties = [p.identifier for p in ad.bl_rna.properties if not p.is_readonly]
objects = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects if o.type == active_obj.type]
objects.remove(active_obj)

for obj in objects :
    if obj.animation_data == None :
        obj.animation_data_create()
    ad2 = obj.animation_data

    for prop in properties:
        setattr(ad2, prop, getattr(ad, prop))
```

here is test run :
[image]

Comment: i definitely need to learn more about the use of python in blender! :)

Comment: @Bithur it really fun once you get started

Comment: i just don't know where to start :)

Comment: Damm i dont know how to put scripts into blender

Comment: @Warianos open the text editor (it's inside blender ), click +New  then copy and paste the script in there, and select your objects , then click Run script

Comment: @Warianos the active object is the one selected last

Comment: Okay i will try it

Comment: It doesnt work it says "fails, locking python" something like that

Comment: @Warianos are both armature identical (bone names ), also is the one with the animation is the active (selected last) ?

Comment: Yes, both equals, its strange..

Comment: @Warianos let me check again and i'll be back

Comment: @Warianos did you try it this way?

Comment: @Warianos is it working?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, was sleeping, going to try it, im really sorry i tought that it was the objecto it self and not the armature object, going to try now

Comment: Man, it really worked, omg this is awsome. Why blender does not have this implemented yet in it?

Comment: very good, I'm having issues because the armature I am copying to is using quartenion for rotation. How do I change your code to perform a copy and paste in pose mode and then add a LocRotPos via script?

Answer (score 7):

Select both objects and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>>*Animation data*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i tried but i failed dunno if im doing it correctlly, here´s a screen shot http://gyazo.com/c5c8e97316a19ed5260aa2e9eb83a46c 

I want to copy the keyframes from the other armature to the  lowest one :S

Comment: You selected it in object mode, correct?

Comment: Yes yes, i did it in object mode

Comment: Thanks for the help, it really links de animation, but i couldnt put it in the same armature without destroying the other animations